# Chat reputation update

Tags: discussion, chat

I just gained two more reputation points, and unlocked the right to chat in chatrooms. Knowing that, I went straight away to [StackOverflow chatrooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), but my reputation points were not updated. Is the update delay normal, and why does it exist?

Comment: There is a definite delay in syncing rep between Stack Overflow, which is updated in real time, and meta.SO. From the existence of your question I assume the same is true for chat.SO as well, it may even use the same database entry as meta.SO does. It usually takes less than 10 minutes in my experience but someone else can likely clarify the exact timing.

Comment: Reputation syncs between [so] and Meta Stack Overflow every hour. I'd assume this to be similar for chat (within an hour).

Comment: There is definitely a delay between SO and chat.so. That goes for rep, avatar change, name change, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It exists because chat is a separate system from the main sites - you can have a main-site user account without a corresponding chat user account (and vice-versa, although that involves deleting your main-site account...)

Chat user accounts are periodically refreshed via the API, but until this happens changes to reputation or other attributes in the main-site user aren't reflected in the corresponding chat user.